# Is it possible to use Google apps with Tor?

Tags: google, captcha

I can't access any email or accounts whatsoever on Google using Tor because it gives me a CAPTCHA and when I fill that in it just sends me back to the same CAPTCHA but with a new image, in perpetuity. Every time, it says "To continue, please type the characters below".

Plus now every time I try to sign in to Gmail NOT using Tor, but after a Tor attempt, it forces me to create a new password.

Is there a way to get this working to use Google with Tor?

Comment: Can you please ask a question instead of complaining about Google? Do you want to try to use Google with Tor or are you searching for another service to use that is Tor friendly.

Answer (score 2):

If the captcha is via CloudFlare you're probably out of luck. I've got through 30+ captchas and then gave up. It's a known issue that CloudFlare seems very reluctant to remedy. It's not a Google issue (this time).

Comment: There is a huge discussion about this on the tor bugtracker: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/18361

Comment: Indeed there is, it's a serious issue with unfortunate complications for the network.